# Way to make sure Strimzi Kafka cluster replicas in different data center?

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I am working with Apache Kafka and looking to start using Strimzi Kafa. But I am having trouble finding if there is a way to make sure replicas are in a separate data centers. I know kafka has strech clusters which has a single cluster that can be across multiple data centers, but Strimzi doesn't support that from what I can tell.

Is there any way to do this with Strimzi Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

It always depends what you mean with different DC. It could mean different Availability Zones in AWS which will be close to each other and have a good latency. Or some DCs on different continents which would be something Apache Kafka cannot handle. Or maybe something in between.

In general, Strimzi lets you deploy a Kafka cluster within a single Kubernetes cluster. But as long as the latency is good enough, it does not really care whether it is all in one DC or in multiple DCs.

Strimzi gives you too tools how to control this:

- You can configure the [pod scheduling](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/configuring.html#assembly-scheduling-str) to distribute your Kafka broker pods across any *zones* of your cluster
- It lets you configure the [*Rack awareness*](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/configuring.html#type-Rack-reference) which configured the [`broker.rack`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_broker.rack) option in Apache Kafka to make sure your replicas are distributed across the *racks* / *zones*.

You can also use Cruise Control to automatically reassign any replicas which would not be distributed.